# Make single colored regions in image smooth in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I have written some algorithms for an image but the output has some differences from my ground truth which you can see in image below:

[image]

I don't want to make it exactly like the 2nd image but since my images is kinda simple I think there are some filters to at least remove those white curves inside the circles.

Can you suggest me any?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can try using morphological operations like [imclose](https://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/imclose.html)

You need to play with it, to get the desired result.
I used [imbinarize](https://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/imbinarize.html) to convert from `uint8` to black/white.

```
I = imread('https://i.stack.imgur.com/r8XO7.png'); %Read image directly from URL.
R = I(:,:,1);G = I(:,:,2);B = I(:,:,3);
R = imbinarize(255 - R);G = imbinarize(255 - G);B = imbinarize(255 - B); %Convert to binary (use 255-R to inverse polarity because background is white).
SE = strel('disk', 15);
R = imclose(R, SE); %Close opreation.
G = imclose(G, SE);
B = imclose(B, SE);
J = im2uint8(cat(3, ~R, ~G, ~B)); %Use ~R to invert to original polarity.
figure;imshow(J);
```

Almost...
[image]

[It's weird that image is reversed up/down].